# How to respond to this email w/o blaming my former boss?

Tags: colleagues, work-environment, email-etiquette

I recently started at this company as a contractor with a 3 month contract. At my 2 month mark, they requested to extend my contract due to my boss putting in his 2 weeks.

I was NOT his replacement, I was more of a project manager for tasks he assigned. The onboarding process was non existent as he just sent me a few files to read to understand the product (tech company).

It has been a full week since he has left and two situations have arise and I am not sure how to respond to these emails as I do not want to put the blame on my former boss but I was going with his direction on how to complete these tasks.

Issue #1 - We were scheduled to do a webinar with a vendor, one of our colleagues was going to be the speaker but he could not attend it last minute due to it being a bank holiday and he will be traveling. The colleague is blaming it on not having it on his calendar. I had just started my position when this webinar was originally scheduled so I am not sure how the mishap happened. I checked my emails and he confirmed the date and responded with "I will mark these dates off". The manager I have to report to now is asking what happened and how this mishap happened but I don't know how to respond w/o blaming the colleague.

Issue #2 - We have another 2 webinars scheduled, with the speaker of the webinar being someone from our product team. Before my manager left, he requested I set up an e-blast to our database, promoting the webinar, giving me all the information I had to send to our email marketing team. Today the email went out and the speaker received all the bounce back emails and is receiving responses for attendees, over 200 + emails. He is pissed and is wondering what happened and who usually responds to these emails and prospects.

I am not sure how to respond as I JUST STARTED working here and this the first email campaign I sent out and I was going based off of what my previous Manager told me to do.

How do I respond to these emails?

Comment: Are you seriously considering LYING in responding to the emails because you're worried about making someone else look bad? Someone who is leaving the company?

Comment: No? lol I want to respond professionally w/o putting the blame on someone.

Comment: "We were scheduled to do a webinar with a vendor,"  Exactly who scheduled this webinar?

Comment: My previous manager scheduled the webinar. I was CC'd on the emails, so I know my colleague, who was suppose to be the speaker for the webinar, mixed the dates because I was on the emails.

Comment: You respond with the truth and evidence. Hiding stuff will come back on you badly.

Comment: How many days ago did you "just start" working there, please? Did you notice how lame it looks that "one of our colleagues… could not attend it last minute due to it being a bank holiday…" ? Wasn't the question, why that colleague didn't check the calendar before accepting the assignment? How could that reflect on the boss, or you?  Isn't how "traveling…" could matter even less obvious?

Answer (score 11):

For the webinar: You tell that manager exactly what you know, because that's the only thing you know. Your colleague might have agreed with your former boss to change the time and that may have got lost.

For the second webinar: You apologise. You tell the person who is (rightfully) complaining that your boss just left, and you did what your former boss told you. Then you apologise again, ask them to forward these emails to you, and find out who and how this was handled before.